# Nuxt js middleware auth always redirecting to login page even if user is authenticated

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

Vuex State is show right information but nuxt js redirecting it to login page on page load

```
state: {
 auth:Object
 loggedIn:true
 strategy:"local"
 user: Object
}
```

Comment: Create a reproduction on codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the whole reproduction of this issue/question... However here is what I'd use (in ES6 syntax):

```js
// Auth Middleware
export default ({ store, redirect }) => {
  if (!store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    redirect('/login');
  };
};
```

```js
// Redirect Root Middleware
export default ({ store, redirect, route }) => {
  // Redirect the root/home page to login or dashboard based on auth state.
  if (route.path === '/') {
    if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
      redirect('/dashboard');
    } else {
      redirect('/login');
    }
  }
};
```

Both middleware exports are to placed on their separate files and used as shown in [Nuxt's middlware example](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/middleware/).

Comment: Thank  you, but in my casse state is undefined

Comment: @NitinSinghNaruka, this usage example is in a middleware file. Accessing state object is done via store object...`context.store.state`, or with { store } via `store.state` when using object destructuring ES6 syntax. Does this help?